# Error in exporting image GeoTIFF from GEE to Drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, export, error, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to export a GeoTIFF from GEE to my drive and I have gotten this error messege: `Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection.`

This is my code:

```
// defining Thailand polygon----
var thailand = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
         [[[97.3113107563326, 20.46454530076102],
           [97.3113107563326, 5.601181272588201],
           [105.6389474750826, 5.601181272588201],
           [105.6389474750826, 20.46454530076102]]], null, false);

// loading GPM: Monthly Global Precipitation Measurement (GPM) v6----
var gpm = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06');

// Thailand precipitation since 2019-04-01 to 2020-04-01----
var preci_th = gpm
          .select('precipitation')
          .filterBounds(thailand)
          .filterDate('2019-04-01','2020-05-01');
print(preci_th);

// exporting precipitation of Thailand Geotiff image----
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:preci_th,
  description: 'TH-MonthlyPreci_2019-04_2020-04',
  folder: 'G:/My Drive/Google earth engine',
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Export.image.toDrive](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-todrive) function takes an image but `preci_th` is an image collection, with an image per month of the year (starting with April).

You could either select an image from the collection and export it this way, or import a custom function to export the whole collection.

By selecting an image:

```
// select the first image (April) from collection
var preci_th_APR = preci_th.first()

// export precipitation of Thailand Geotiff image----
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:preci_th_APR,
  description: 'TH-MonthlyPreci_2019-04_2020-04',
  folder: 'G:/My Drive/Google earth engine',
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});
```

Or export the collection (all months):

```
// import the batch export function
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

// export precipitation of Thailand **image collection**
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(preci_th, 'Folder', 
                {scale: 1000,  // adjust to desired pixel resolution
                 region: thailand, 
                 type: 'float'})
```